# Our app made by myself work fine in android 9 but does not work in android 6 or older

Tags: android

unfortunately your app has stopped working I have created an app with target api 26 and minimum api 19 when I install it in android 9 it work fine but when I it install in android 6 or older version it gives me error your app has unfortunately stopped working

this is my main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the main Activity is like this

```
package com.imrankhan.pahstoenglishdictionary.khan.wardak.app.englistopashtodictionary;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.SynthesisCallback;
import android.speech.tts.SynthesisRequest;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeechService;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    MenuItem setting;
    Dictionary dictionary;
    AboutUs aboutUs;
    BookMarks bookMarks;
    ditailsFragment d;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    ImageButton btnValumeUp;
    SeekBar valum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        toolbar = findViewById( R.id.toolbar );

        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );

        try {
            dbHelper = new DBHelper( this );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech( MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status!=TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                    textToSpeech.setLanguage( Locale.ENGLISH );
                }
            }
        } );

        // setting.setIcon( getDrawable( R.drawable.usaflage ) );
//        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById( R.id.fab );
//        fab.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Snackbar.make( view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG )
//                        .setAction( "Action", null ).show();
//            }
//        } );
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById( R.id.nav_view );
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close );
        drawer.addDrawerListener( toggle );
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener( this );
        dictionary = new Dictionary();
        aboutUs = new AboutUs();

        d=new ditailsFragment();
        goToFragments(dictionary,true);
        dictionary.setHandleFragments( new HandleFragments() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(String value) {
                String id= Globale.getState( MainActivity.this,"dic_type" );
                int dicTpe= id==null ? R.id.engpa:Integer.valueOf(  id );

                goToFragments( ditailsFragment.getNewInstance( value,dbHelper,dicTpe ),false );
                //System.out.println( value );
            }
        } );
        bookMarks = BookMarks.getNewInstance( dbHelper );
        bookMarks.setHandleFragments( new HandleFragments() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(String value) {

                String id= Globale.getState( MainActivity.this,"dic_type" );
                int dicTpe= id==null ? R.id.engpa:Integer.valueOf(  id );

                goToFragments( ditailsFragment.getNewInstance( value,dbHelper,dicTpe ),false );
            }
        } );

        //Search EditeTex click event enablede
        final EditText search = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.search );
        search.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                dictionary.filterValue( s.toString() );
                Editable searchText = search.getText();
            goToFragments( dictionary,false );
                //return  true;
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        } );

        // setting.setIcon( getDrawable( R.drawable.usaflage ) );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen( GravityCompat.START )) {
            drawer.closeDrawer( GravityCompat.START );
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //  setting.setIcon( getDrawable( R.drawable.usaflage ) );
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu );
        setting =menu.findItem( R.id.action_settings );
        String id= Globale.getState( this,"dic_type" );
        if(id != null){
            onOptionsItemSelected( menu.findItem( Integer.valueOf( id ) ) );
        }
        else{
            ArrayList<String> source = dbHelper.getWord(R.id.engpa );
            dictionary.resetDataSource( source );
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (R.id.action_settings==id)return true;
// if(R.id.action_clear==id){
        //  System.out.println( "clear" );
        //     }

       // Global.saveState( this,"dic_type",String.valueOf( id ) );
        Globale.saveSate( this,"dic_type",String.valueOf( id ) );
        ArrayList<String> source =dbHelper.getWord(id);

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        if (id == R.id.paeng)
        {

            dictionary.resetDataSource( source);
        }else if(id==R.id.engpa){

            dictionary.resetDataSource( source);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id==R.id.nav_bookmark){

                goToFragments( bookMarks,false);
        }
        else if (id==R.id.nav_rate){
            goToFragments( aboutUs,false );

        }else if(id==R.id.nav_share){
            Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType( "tesxt/plain" );
            String shareBody="my body";
            String subDody ="sub";
            intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareBody);
            intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subDody);
            startActivity( Intent.createChooser( intent,"Share Via" ) );
        }else if (id==R.id.exit){
            System.exit( 0 );
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
        drawer.closeDrawer( GravityCompat.START );
        return true;
    }
    void  goToFragments(Fragment fragment, boolean isTop){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace( R.id.conttener,fragment);
        if(!isTop){
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack( null );
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        String activeFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById( R.id.conttener ).getClass().getSimpleName();
        if( activeFragment.equals( BookMarks.class.getSimpleName() )){
            setting.setVisible( false );
            toolbar.findViewById( R.id.search ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
            toolbar.setTitle( "Bookmark" );

        }
//       else if ( activeFragment.equals( AboutUs.class.getSimpleName() )){
//            setting.setVisible( false );
//            toolbar.findViewById( R.id.search ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
//            toolbar.setTitle( "About us" );
//
//        }
        else {
            setting.setVisible( true );
            toolbar.findViewById( R.id.search ).setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            toolbar.setTitle( "" );
        }
        return  true;
    }

}
```

this is my full logcat

```
02-10 06:35:02.147 1535-1535/? E/Zygote: v2
02-10 06:35:02.147 1535-1535/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10362
02-10 06:35:02.147 1535-1535/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
02-10 06:35:02.147 1535-1535/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0025
02-10 06:35:02.147 1535-1535/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
02-10 06:35:02.147 1535-1535/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.imrankhan.pahstoenglishdictionary.khan.wardak.app.englistopashtodictionary 
02-10 06:35:02.147 1535-1535/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-10 06:35:02.187 1535-1535/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
02-10 06:35:02.187 1535-1535/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
02-10 06:35:02.247 1535-1535/? D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
02-10 06:35:02.267 1535-1541/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
02-10 06:35:02.277 1535-1535/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.imrankhan.pahstoenglishdictionary.khan.wardak.app.englistopashtodictionary-1/lib/arm
02-10 06:35:02.327 1535-1545/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12449(661KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 85% free, 1090KB/7MB, paused 5.635ms total 33.217ms
02-10 06:35:02.367 1535-1535/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
02-10 06:35:02.597 1535-1535/? D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-10 06:35:02.637 1535-1535/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f070067 (t=6 e=103) (error -75)
02-10 06:35:02.647 1535-1535/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f070077 (t=6 e=119) (error -75)
02-10 06:35:02.647 1535-1535/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f070076 (t=6 e=118) (error -75)
02-10 06:35:02.647 1535-1535/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f070069 (t=6 e=105) (error -75)
02-10 06:35:02.647 1535-1535/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f070067 (t=6 e=103) (error -75)
02-10 06:35:02.647 1535-1535/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-10 06:35:02.657 1535-1535/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.imrankhan.pahstoenglishdictionary.khan.wardak.app.englistopashtodictionary, PID: 1535
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.imrankhan.pahstoenglishdictionary.khan.wardak.app.englistopashtodictionary/com.imrankhan.pahstoenglishdictionary.khan.wardak.app.englistopashtodictionary.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.imrankhan.pahstoenglishdictionary.khan.wardak.app.englistopashtodictionary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.imrankhan.pahstoenglishdictionary.khan.wardak.app.englistopashtodictionary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.imrankhan.pahstoenglishdictionary.khan.wardak.app.englistopashtodictionary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070067
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2598)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:491)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:519)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:460)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:117)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:250)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:172)
        at android.support.design.widget.Navigation
02-10 06:35:10.987 1535-1535/com.imrankhan.pahstoenglishdictionary.khan.wardak.app.englistopashtodictionary I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1535 SIG: 9
```

and this is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.imrankhan.pahstoenglishdictionary.khan.wardak.app.englistopashtodictionary"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Please share the full Logcat error

Comment: as per the logs, the error is in `<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView/>` at line `16` in your `xml` file

Comment: I know that but what is the solution